# Bundle really big production React app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, bundle, font-awesome, bundling-and-minification

I decided to build a react app from scratch (all setup it's need) to understand better how things happens behind the scenes (as we have those things already setup by `create-react-app` for example), everything is fine but the bundle size is really big (at least I think it is)

I've setup my app like this:
[image]

this are my configs:
**webpack.common**

```
const path = require('path');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: ["babel-polyfill", path.join(__dirname, "./src/index.js")],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "html-loader",
                        options: {minimize: true}
                    }
                ]
            },
            {test: /\.css$/, use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']},
            {test: /\.(pdf|jpg|png|gif|svg|ico)$/, use: 'url-loader'}
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: "./src/index.html",
            filename: "./index.html"
        })
    ],
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: 'all'
        }
    }
};
```

**webpack.prod**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const CompressionPlugin = require("compression-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: 'production',
    devtool: 'source-map',
    plugins: [
        new UglifyJSPlugin({
            sourceMap: true
        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
        }),
        new CompressionPlugin()
    ]
});
```

**and this is my output**

```
Hash: 19b5647860c66f778d8f
Version: webpack 4.12.0
Time: 75351ms
Built at: 2018-06-13 20:07:36
                 Asset       Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
       vendors~main.js   3.07 MiB       0  [emitted]  [big]  vendors~main
               main.js    648 KiB       1  [emitted]  [big]  main
   vendors~main.js.map   6.51 MiB       0  [emitted]         vendors~main
           main.js.map    671 KiB       1  [emitted]         main
          ./index.html  255 bytes          [emitted]         
       ./index.html.gz  178 bytes          [emitted]         
        main.js.map.gz    476 KiB          [emitted]  [big]  
            main.js.gz    468 KiB          [emitted]  [big]  
    vendors~main.js.gz    967 KiB          [emitted]  [big]  
vendors~main.js.map.gz   1.76 MiB          [emitted]  [big]  
Entrypoint main [big] = vendors~main.js vendors~main.js.map main.js main.js.map
  [23] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 489 bytes {0} [built]
  [74] ./node_modules/redux-saga/es/internal/sagaHelpers/index.js + 4 modules 5.55 KiB {0} [built]
       |    5 modules
 [180] ./node_modules/react-router-dom/es/index.js + 30 modules 75.7 KiB {0} [built]
       |    31 modules
 [280] ./node_modules/react-redux/es/index.js + 23 modules 43 KiB {0} [built]
       |    24 modules
 [449] ./node_modules/redux-saga/es/index.js + 4 modules 30 KiB {0} [built]
       |    5 modules
 [471] ./src/client/modules/auth/redux/auth.saga.js 1.51 KiB {1} [built]
 [472] ./src/client/redux/sagas.js 938 bytes {1} [built]
 [473] ./src/client/modules/auth/redux/auth.reducer.js 925 bytes {1} [built]
 [474] ./src/client/redux/reducers.js 393 bytes {1} [built]
 [796] ./src/client/utils/themes.js 706 bytes {1} [built]
 [897] ./src/client/App.js 4.42 KiB {1} [built]
 [899] ./node_modules/css-loader!./src/index.css 435 bytes {1} [built]
 [900] ./src/index.css 1.05 KiB {1} [built]
 [908] ./src/index.js 1.29 KiB {1} [built]
[1111] multi babel-polyfill ./src/index.js 40 bytes {1} [built]
    + 1097 hidden modules

WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
This can impact web performance.
Assets: 
  vendors~main.js (3.07 MiB)
  main.js (648 KiB)
  main.js.map.gz (476 KiB)
  main.js.gz (468 KiB)
  vendors~main.js.gz (967 KiB)
  vendors~main.js.map.gz (1.76 MiB)

WARNING in entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.
Entrypoints:
  main (3.7 MiB)
      vendors~main.js
      main.js


WARNING in webpack performance recommendations: 
You can limit the size of your bundles by using import() or require.ensure to lazy load some parts of your application.
For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
     1 asset
    Entrypoint undefined = ./index.html
    [0] ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/index.html 159 bytes {0} [built]
Done in 84.75s.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Am I missing something? I think the bundle shouldn't be that big. During my research I came across with this https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6724
I'm using the new fontawesome pro and indeed removing it from my app reduces almost 2MB from the bundle...Anyone can help me with this? I'm out of ideas!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think if you've imported your `fontawesome` in your `.js` file, then webpack must have all the assets it needs, including `css` and `webfonts`. According to `webpack`'s documentation:

> `Tree Shaking` is relies on the static structure of ES2015 module syntax, i.e. import and export

So when fontawesome is `imported`, all of these assets must be `bundle`. When looking at `fontawesome` `downloaded` file, I see that it's exactly about 2MB in size.

So if you want to reduce the bundled file's size,  you can use `fontawesome` CDN and include it in your `index.html` file with `link` tag. In this case, using `html-webpack-plugin` template

[image][image]

Comment: As I've posted, I think the problem is more FontAwesome related because if I'm not mistaken, the unused code should not be bundled (tree shaking) but the way fontawesome implemented for react it forces everything to be part of the bundle. Thanks for your comment, I'll try to use CDN.